# How to create child routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i just implemented breadcrumb for my project and in routes file it required the child routes in child array. So I did this:

```
 {
    path: 'customercreation/:formType',
    component: CustomerCreationComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Customer Creation'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path:
          ':customerId/:stepId/:EntityId',
        component: FormComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Form'
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

But when I am routing to child component, it showing me the parent component, but routes is changing. And in the same case when I am writing child part out side of child array, I mean new routes, then it working properly, What I did wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `CustomerCreationComponent`.
There it will output it's children.